# Galaxy S2 on Android 4.0.4 won't vibrate

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, vibration

How can I set my phone to just vibrate? No sound; just vibration. I just got the upgraded version of the S2, and my phone won't vibrate. I tried everything.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `System > Sound > Ring mode > Vibrate`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the "quick toggles" in your notification area when you "drag down" the notification bar (IMHO the S2 has this by default)?

[image: SGS2 Notification Area]
<sup>SGS2 Notification Area (click image to enlarge)</sup>

If so, simply tap the "speaker symbol" there to switch modes between "ringtone", "vibrate", and "silent" (the symbol then will switch as well to indicate the current mode).